# Showing an inequality for analytic functions on the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in the first open quadrant and bounded there. Also, let $Im f(z) \geq 0$. Then for any $z_0$ in the quadrant, I have to show

$\mid (f(z)-f(z_0))/(f(z)-\overline{f(z_0)}) \mid\space \leq \space \mid (z^2-z_0^2)/(z^2-\overline{(z_0)^2}) \mid$

I tried some geometric means of distance, but cannot find a way through. The conditions given seem too meager to derive any meaningful hints...Could anyone please help me? It's so frustrating....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $Q$ as the open first quadrant, $H=\{\Im(z) > 0\}$, $D$ the open unit disk.

Note that $q: z \in Q \longmapsto z^2 \in H$ is a biholomorphism.

Note also that for $g_w: w \in H$, $z \in H \longmapsto \frac{z-w}{z-\overline{w}} \in D$ is a biholomorphism mapping $w$ to $0$.

Indeed, it is a homography centered outside $H$, that maps $H$ into $D$ and $\partial H$ into $\partial D$ and to a circle, so it maps $\partial H$ to $\partial D$ and thus $H$ to $D$.

Now, just notice that $h=g_{f(z_0)} \circ f \circ q^{-1} \circ g_{q(z_0)}^{-1}$ is a holomorphic function from $D$ to itself, so $|h(z)| \leq |z|$, ie $|g_{f(z_0)} \circ f(z)| \leq |g_{q(z_0)} \circ q(z)|.$

Comment: Is $H$ the upper half plane?

Comment: @Keith: yes, it is.